# Como incluir uma string no banco de dados a partir de um input array com Laravel?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, formulário, input

preciso incluir uma dado em forma de string na tabela do meu banco que pegarei pelo input, que por sua vez é um array. Segue o form para vocês verem como está.

```
<div class="form-inline col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="create-contest-theme#1" class="control-label">1º Tema: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="theme[]" id="create-contest-theme#1" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="create-contest-theme#2" class="control-label">2º Tema: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="theme[]" id="create-contest-theme#2" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="create-contest-theme#3" class="control-label">3º Tema: </label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="theme[]" id="create-contest-theme#3" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

A action desse form aponta para a função create do meu controller:

```
public function create(CreateRequest $request){
    $inputs = $request->except('_token');

    $contest = Contest::create($inputs);

    return $contest;
}
```

A model Constest

```
  class Contest extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'contests';
}
```

E a minha grande dúvida é: Como tratar esse input `theme` para que seja uma string quando for armazenado?

Answer (score 0):

Faltam informações, mas vou supor que você você esteja usando o **Laravel 5.4** e pretenda salvar cada item do *array* como um registro no banco.

Você precisa da propriedade **$fillable** no model para fazer uma [Mass Assigment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Quando você preenche um modelo do Eloquent com um array através das funções `create`, `fill` ou `update`, por questões de segurança é necessário dizer quais campos serão aceitos.

**Exemplo**

```
class Contest extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contests';
    protected $fillable = ['campo_1', 'campo_2', 'campo_3'];
}
```

Comment: Não é isso que quero fazer,  o que acontece é o seguinte: Tenho 3 inputs com o mesmo `name=theme[]`, que vai me dar um array. Porém para guardar essa informação no banco queria transformar esse array em uma string com um delimitador usando `ìmplode`por exemplo: `theme[0] = ação, theme[1]= drama`  eu quero que isso seja uma string igual a **"ação,drama"**

Comment: Por isso sinalizei que faltam informações na sua questão. É necessário elaborar melhor para que você possa receber auxílio de forma mais rápida e precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei o que queria, a solução era bem simples, eu que não entendia como as coisas funcionavam muito bem no laravel, foi questão de ler a documentação e tudo ficou mais claro.

Solução:

```
public function create(CreateRequest $request){
    $inputs = $request->except('_token');
    $inputs['themes'] = implode(",", inputs['themes']);

    $contest = Contest::create($inputs);

    return $contest;
}
```

O que eu estava fazendo antes era tentar mudar o valor da `request` quando deveria mudar o valor do array retornado `$inputs`